# On topic to put out my solutions of self study questions and ask for confirmation?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, solution-verification

I am mostly self tutoring myself on the math behind fluid dynamics using an advanced textbook. So the book has several problems. Is it OK to post the problem solution as I do it and ask for confirmation?

Comment: You can find several discussions here on meta among the questions tagged ([meta-tag:solution-verification]). There are also many discussions about ([meta-tag:homework]), but since you wrote that *you are self tutoring*, it seems that this is not really a homework.

Comment: @MartinSleziak - I modified my title. So general consensus is that it is allowed but to be used with extreme caution am I correct ?

Comment: I do not know anything about *extreme caution*. I'd say that I summarized what I can say about this at the beginning of my answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/is-it-okay-if-i-use-this-site-to-have-someone-check-my-work-or-give-a-solution/23256#23256).